# Can someone tell me what this Rails debug message means? I'd like to fix the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the ruby debugger on all my pages but I never understood the error message. Can someone walk me through this? I think I know what a indifferent hash is (key can be sym or str), but I don't know why it matters. The last phrase, permitted: false, scares me. Does it have something to do with strong parameters? Is it the action "create" that is not permitted?

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
   parameters: 
   !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: 

 nlXTh3Ml5zzRAF9gPFc5KXzAbCoqXXyduq (shortened) ==
 stripeToken: tok_1Dv(shortened)X
 user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
   card_brand: Visa
   card_exp_month: '12'
   card_exp_year: '2021'
   card_last4: '4242'
 controller: pledge_charges
 action: create
  permitted: false
```

Comment: what's the error message Tom?

Comment: Looks to me like a YAML dump of a `params` that hasn't been through the usual `params.require(...).permit(...)` process, the lack of a `permit` call is probably where the `permitted: false` is coming from.

Comment: My concern is the permitted: false statement. All of the attributes are listed in my strong params, and as far as an error, I guess there's none, because the request and response are working. That permitted: false concerns me.

Comment: @TomConnolly are you manually setting any values to instance variables etc. in your controller actions like this: `card_last_4 = params[:card_last4]` - if you do, that could explain why permitted is false, but everything still working?

Comment: No, I was wrong, BKSpurgeon. The card info is exactly what is NOT working. I'm struggling with how to save it to the database.

Comment: Have you set up strong parameters? Can you edit the question and explain in more detail the issue. I am guessing you post something to the create action and it fails to save? Can you show the controller code and what is posted to the controller (check your logfile).

Comment: It might be because I don't care to save the token I didn't list it in permitted params. I'll check that out later. Thanks everyone for responding to an old man.